# How to set a mask to entire layout?

Tags: android, animation, mask

I already worked with different mask libraries that set a mask to images (ex: https://github.com/siyamed/android-shape-imageview) but i want to mask **different layouts** not just imageView. So i tried  [MaskableLayout](https://github.com/christophesmet/android_maskable_layout)

It is good until i start animating views in the MaskableLayout. it has a very bad lag in the ui as i described [here](https://github.com/christophesmet/android_maskable_layout/issues/7).
Is there any replacement for this?

Comment: seems that `MaskableLayout` has inefficient implementation, you need to find a better one ;-)

Comment: make a custom layout class (FrameLayout / LinearLayout / RelativeLayout / whatever) and override `dispatchDraw` method

Comment: I know this, but i have no clue with drawing and paint and mask :(

Comment: see porter-duff modes and `Canvas#saveLayer`